# Remove strings after each first word in a text file

Tags: unix, sed, awk, cat

**File1:**

```
hello   (OPTION1)   123456   123456   123456
world   (OPTION1)   123456   123456   123456
foo     (OPTION1)   123456   123456   123456
bar     (OPTION1)   123456   123456   123456
```

**How would one remove each string after each first word in the textfile File1?**

This would probably be down with awk/sed/cat - but I cannot figure it out. I'm still new to editing via these utilities - perhaps others will benefit from my question.

The first words are not predictive (no wild cards), each first word is unique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

awk one liner:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' < inputfile > outputfile
```

sed one liner:

```
sed 's/^\([A-Za-z0-9]*\).*/\1/' < inputfile > outpufile
```

Comment: Both commands achieved the outcome, as did those below. Awk seems to be a very interesting utility. Thanks to Igor and pavium for their time, it is well appreciated!

Comment: It's not necessary to redirect the input file in either case. Both programs accept filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 4):

why to use the those tools even after after having the cut command

```
cut -f1 -d"\t" filename
```

Comment: because cut just cuts and nothing else. awk cuts and greps and seds and counts plus a whole lot more.

Comment: cut "does one thing and does it well".

Answer (score 3):

try

```
awk '{print $1}' filename > filename2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just trim everything from the first white space onwards:

```
sed '\s.*$//' <File1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just for fun, you could do it with perl

perl -ne '@a=split; print "$a[0]\n"' < file

Answer (score 0):

To remove everything after a delimiter:

`cut -f1 -d"\t" inputfile > outputfile`

`\t` can be replaced with any other delimiter (e.g., `;`) based on your specific case.